# Is the following quote grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

"Deep inside of you is more strength than you've ever known" -Mel Greig

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Shouldn't it be "has more strength" or "is stronger" instead of "is more strength"?

If it is correct, could you explain me what it means exactly?

Comment: Why do you think it should be _has_? Please edit your question to explain your reasoning. As it stands, your question falls foul of the rule here that you must always show your research when asking, and will likely be put on hold as being off-topic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am researching by asking here! If I knew the answer of your question, I wouldn't ask my question at the first place.

Comment: The original is perfectly fine English. Both your alternative wordings are not English at all. You're either missing a subject entirely, or trying to pass *inside* for a noun, which in this context it cannot be. You will need to replace *deep* with a *the* in order for that to work. Which will get you something hideous indeed.

Comment: Sorry, but that’s not how the site works. You’re expected to at least look in a dictionary or grammar book (depending on the topic) and at the very least explain _why_ you think as you do. The more details you give, the better and more helpful the answers you get will be.

Comment: Can I say "I am strength"? I can say "I am strong",  OR "I have strength", right? So, how can inside of me is strength? That's the thing I can't understand.

Comment: "Deep inside of me [there] is strength..."

Comment: The aspect of grammar that you need to research in order to understand why your sentence is grammatical is called _fronting_. Here is one page with explanations and examples: https://www.thoughtco.com/fronting-in-grammar-1690875

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as:

> "Deep inside of you***, there*** is more strength than you've ever known"

Strength can't "have" something, so "has" does not work. Consider these:

> Deep inside the cave is a bear.
>
> Strength is deep inside you.

These both seem grammatically correct, right? It's the same thing with your quote - just phrased differently. However, to use a derivative of "has", you could say:

> You have more strength deep inside you than you've ever known.

Comment: The dog is inside the house: It sounds OK.
Inside the house is the dog: It sounds not OK.

To be clear, are you saying that "Inside the house is the dog" is also correct?

Comment: Technically, it would be "inside the house, there is a dog" or "inside you, there is strength", but the word "there" can be omitted. So your quote might be more accurate if she had said "THERE is more strength", but as it is, her quote is still correct.

Comment: English is a weird language. Most languages don't always have a binary of "right" and "wrong" grammar, simply because of how they develop. But the fact that English spread over so many different cultures at various points in history has caused it to have even more instances of this than one might find in many other languages.